# Clover bootloader is missing bootable hard drives

Tags: uefi, bootloader

I have two installs of Clover EFI

- Clover on my SSD
- Clover on my USB

The SSD Clover - Loads clover properly, **no option to boot from hard drive** I want to fix this.

The USB Clover - Loads clover properly, lists options to boot, including hard drive

Both of them allow me to boot into UEFI shell, but from there it is unclear what to do.

How would I go about adding the hard drive to the clover boot list? Or have it autodetected? In grub2, for example, you can just tell it to reconfigure. In windows, you can use BCDEdit. But for Clover, I am lost.

Comment: Clover is basically an EFI boot loader. Under EFI, disks are not booted; boot loader programs stored in files on disks are booted. That said, Clover also has the ability to transfer control to BIOS-mode boot loaders stored on disks' MBRs. Thus, it's not clear if the boot option that has disappeared is for an EFI-mode boot loader *file* or for a BIOS-mode boot loader *in a disk's MBR* (or in a partition's PBR). The answer is likely to be different depending on which of these is the case. As Clover is also a Hackintosh boot loader, you're also likely to get a better answer on a Hackintosh forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an incorrect `config.plist` file in the `/EFI/CLOVER` directory. I simply replaced it with an older working one. (You could also regenerate one)

Comment: You should mark this question as solved.